# Evitando el uso de For

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Una vez más por aquí intentando hacer las cosas sin el uso de `for`, tengo un problema que tiene solución con `for` pero me gustaría darle un enfoque sin `for`.

El problema consiste en que tengo unos datos con dias y quiero crear una variable en el mismo data que sea el mes al que corresponden esos datos.

```
inicio <- c("01012018","01022018","01032018","01042018","01052018","01062018",
            "01072018","01082018","01092018","01102018","01112018","01122018")

fin <- c("31012018","28022018","31032018","30042018","31052018","30062018",
         "31072018","31082018","30092018","31102018","30112018","31122018")

mes <- c("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio",
         "julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre")

fechas <- data.table(inicio,fin,mes)

dias <- c("01032018","02042018","14062018","13012018","20102018")

datos <- data.table(dias)

datos$mes <- data.table(ifelse(fechas$inicio <= datos$dias & datos$dias <= fechas$fin,fechas$mes,"error"))
```

La salida que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
       dias     mes
1: 01032018   enero
2: 02042018 febrero
3: 14062018   marzo
4: 13012018   abril
5: 20102018    mayo
```

Como podeis comprabar la solucion no es correcta, además, obtengo el siguiente aviso:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fechas$inicio <= datos$dias :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In datos$dias <= fechas$fin :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 12 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'mes' (7 unused)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios temas en la forma en que has planteado el problema, veamos:

1. En primer lugar, entiendo que este es algún tipo de ejercicio, por que la obtención de un mes a partir de la fecha es algo trivial con funciones de fecha.
2. Uno de los problemas, es que no estás trabajando con datos de tipo fecha sino con caracteres, por lo que las comparaciones serán por el orden alfabetico, en cuyo caso las fechas tal como las has formateado no sirven. Para poder ordenar correctamente una fecha en forma de caracter el formato debe estar armado según las magnitudes (mayor a menor) es decir deben estar en formato `YYYYMMDD`.
3. El `ifelse` no sirve en este caso, normalmente se aplica sobre los datos de un único objeto o de dos objetos consistentes en dimensiones, en este caso `fechas` y `datos` no son consistentes fila a fila, de ahi los Warnings, y los resultados

#### Solución

En primer lugar vamos a "reformatear" las fechas

```
library(data.table)

inicio <- c("01012018","01022018","01032018","01042018","01052018","01062018",
            "01072018","01082018","01092018","01102018","01112018","01122018")
fin <- c("31012018","28022018","31032018","30042018","31052018","30062018",
         "31072018","31082018","30092018","31102018","30112018","31122018")
mes <- c("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio",
         "julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre")

# Formateamos las fechas en la forma YYYYMMDD 
inicio <- paste0(substring(inicio,5,8),substring(inicio,3,4),substring(inicio,1,2))
fin <- paste0(substring(fin,5,8),substring(fin,3,4),substring(fin,1,2))

fechas <- data.table(inicio,fin,mes)

dias <- c("01032018","02042018","14062018","13012018","20102018")
# Formateamos las fechas en la forma YYYYMMDD 
dias <- paste0(substring(dias,5,8),substring(dias,3,4),substring(dias,1,2))
datos <- data.table(dias)
```

Como en este caso los intervalos de fechas no se solapan, podemos usar solo uno de los límites, es decir `fechas$inicio` y la función `findIntervals()`  de la siguiente forma:

```
datos$mes <- fechas$mes[findInterval(datos$dias, intervalos)]
datos

       dias     mes
1: 20180301   marzo
2: 20180402   abril
3: 20180614   junio
4: 20180113   enero
5: 20181020 octubre
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Efectivamente es un tipo de ejercicio donde aparecen fechas etc

Me ha servido, soluciona mi problema.

Gracias por tu trabajo.
Un saludo.